# Equation brackets after frac remain small

Tags: equations, brackets, fractions

My brackets in the equation remain small, between brackets I have a fraction, usually the brackets auto size and become the same size and enclose the fraction.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eqn:arr}
k(T)=k^0\texttt{exp}(\frac{E}{R}(\frac{1}{T_{ref}})-\frac{1}{T})
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `k(T)=k^0\texttt{exp}\left(\frac{E}{R}\left(\frac{1}{T_{ref}}\right)-\frac{1}{T}\right)`

Comment: Not sure why `\texttt{exp}`; anyway, it should be `\mathtt{exp}`: try your input inside a theorem statement and you'll see the difference.

Comment: This is not about typesetting, but don't you want $\frac{E}{R}\left(\frac{1}{T_\text{ref}}-\frac{1}{T}\right)$ in the exponent (i.e. aren't you inner parentheses wrong)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brackets in equations only auto size if you ask them to. You can either set the size manually with `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg` or `\Bigg` or let LaTeX compute it for you with `\left(…\right)`. You need to use the former if the latter gives the wrong sizes or fails to compile, e.g. if you have brackets across several lines or some form of `\underbrace`. In your case,

```
\begin{equation}\label{eqn:arr}
k(T)=k^0\texttt{exp}\left(\frac{E}{R}\left(\frac{1}{T_{ref}}\right)-\frac{1}{T}\right)
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 4):

For your specific problem:

- use pairs of `\left(` and `\right)` to get brackets that automatically adapt their size to the contents. If you are not satisfied with the automatically assigned size (like here: both pairs of brackets will get the same size, although being nested), you can manually adjust the size by using `\big(`, `\bigg(`, `\Big(` or `\Bigg(`, respectively.

Other comments:

- use the `\exp` command instead of `\texttt{exp}`
- you probably want to have "ref" typed as text, not as math symbol. Use `\mathrm` for that
- it is better to post a Minimal Working Example, that doesn't include things not necessery to reproduce the problem. In your case, you can drop all the packages.

Your code:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
k(T)=k^0\exp\Bigg(\frac{E}{R}\left(\frac{1}{T_{\mathrm{ref}}}\right)-\frac{1}{T}\Bigg)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to size the parentheses yourself (maybe with `\left` and `\right`).

Here I present the formula in four different styles, comparing to the original one.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\let\exp\relax % undefine it
\DeclareMathOperator{\exp}{\mathtt{exp}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align} % for several examples
k(T) &= k^0\exp(\frac{E}{R}(\frac{1}{T_{\mathrm{ref}}})-\frac{1}{T}) \\
k(T) &= k^0\exp\left(\frac{E}{R}\left(\frac{1}{T_{\mathrm{ref}}}\right)-\frac{1}{T}\right) \\
k(T) &= k^0\exp\Bigl(\frac{E}{R}\Bigl(\frac{1}{T_{\mathrm{ref}}}\Bigr)-\frac{1}{T}\Bigr) \\
k(T) &= k^0\exp\biggl(\frac{E}{R}\biggl(\frac{1}{T_{\mathrm{ref}}}\biggr)-\frac{1}{T}\biggr) \\
k(T) &= k^0\exp\biggl(\frac{E}{R}\Bigl(\,\frac{1}{T_{\mathrm{ref}}}\,\Bigr)-\frac{1}{T}\biggr)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

The first is your input, clearly not acceptable. Number 2 shows `\left` and `\right`, which add unwanted spaces (compare with number 4, where the sizes are the same).

Number 3 and number 4 use the same size for all parentheses; choose one style and be consistent. The last one uses different size for the inner and the outer parentheses.

Note the redefinition of `\exp`: `\texttt{exp}` is wrong to begin with, because it would give italic in a theorem statement.

On the other hand, I'd use the standard `\exp`. Redefining it will ensure that when you change your mind you'll not need to chase the document for `\mathttt{exp}` or the like, but just remove or modify the redefinition.

[image]

On the other hand, the inner parentheses seem redundant, in this particular case. Again, I propose four different styles, in addition to the “non sized” style.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\let\exp\relax % undefine it
\DeclareMathOperator{\exp}{\mathtt{exp}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align} % for several examples
k(T) &= k^0\exp(\frac{E}{R}\frac{1}{T_{\mathrm{ref}}}-\frac{1}{T}) \\
k(T) &= k^0\exp\left(\frac{E}{R}\frac{1}{T_{\mathrm{ref}}}-\frac{1}{T}\right) \\
k(T) &= k^0\exp\Bigl(\frac{E}{R}\frac{1}{T_{\mathrm{ref}}}-\frac{1}{T}\Bigr) \\
k(T) &= k^0\exp\biggl(\frac{E}{R}\frac{1}{T_{\mathrm{ref}}}-\frac{1}{T}\biggr) \\
k(T) &= k^0\exp\biggl(\frac{E}{R}\,\frac{1}{T_{\mathrm{ref}}}-\frac{1}{T}\biggr)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]